# How to fix the issue in uploading an app error : 10.1(UNSUPPORTED: Local iOS SDK is 10.2 which does not match)?

Tags: ios, lua, sdk, coronasdk

> I created app using Lua language using Corona SDK  and when I try to
> create a build or Send it to App Store, it displays these errors below
>
> UNSUPPORTED IOS SDK Mismatch
>
> The version of iOS SDK (10.2) that's installed on this computer does
> not match the target iOS version (10.1). You may encounter issues
> building or incompatibilities at runtime.
>
> Anyone can help me with this issue? Any help will be appreciated.
> Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  You need to download the latest daily build from Corona Labs and then build using that version.  Daily builds are found here:

https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/daily-builds

Comment: Okay I will check it. Thanks

Comment: If it worked, would greatly appreciate an up-vote.  Thanks.

Comment: That's a good help but my IOS SDK is always updated.  You know what? That problem was fixed when I purchased the $99/year for splash screen control. This might be the Corona SDK problem. Anyway, I'm gonna up-vote your answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @RainshowerDemonbreaker.  I had also purchased the Splash Screen plug-in.  I did not correlate that purchase to solving the problem.  Thanks for the up-vote and thanks for figuring out the real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From Corona [blog](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2015/04/22/xcode-requirements-ios-8-3-ios-8-4-beta/)

> Changes to Xcode Requirements
>
> Starting with 2015.2616, Corona
>   Simulator will be more stringent about the version of Xcode you have
>   installed (older versions work like before, in a less stringent
>   manner). In particular, when you select a particular target iOS
>   version, you must have the corresponding version of Xcode installed.
>   For example, if you want to target iOS 8.3, you must install Xcode 6.3
>   which includes iOS 8.3 SDK.

Also, from [this](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/65957-xcode-and-sdk-version/) post you can read that for  iOS 10 SDK you need install Xcode 8. So I guess for  iOS 10.2 SDK you need Xcode 8.2 (I'm not sure which one exactly will fit). What is more you need most recent version of Corona:

- [stable build](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/corona-sdk) (requires Xcode 8.1 or later, the macOS Simulator requires macOS 10.10 or later, [more information](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/corona-sdk-release-notes-build-20162992)) or
- [daily builds](https://developer.coronalabs.com/downloads/daily-builds/).

Note: I'm using only Win7 for Corona SDK.